# Analogia entre POO e banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, orientação-a-objetos, entity-framework

Estive lendo a respeito do Entity Framework, que ele tem uns recursos de transformar classes em tabelas e objetos em linhas. Achei super interessante!

Até que ponto essa analogia é válida? Se é assim, então qual seria o análogo duma interface em BD?

E o que seria, em POO, o análogo duma tabela ponte?

Faz sentido estender essa analogia, ou não?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Se é assim, então qual seria o análogo duma interface em BD?

Nada.

> E o que seria, em POO, o análogo duma tabela ponte?

Não tem nada de especial. O máximo que pode ocorrer, mas geralmente não bem assim, é que um *array* seja usado para fazer a ligação entre as tabelas que se relacionam.

> Faz sentido estender essa analogia, ou não?

Não, nada a ver.

A única coisa que o EF faz é pegar os campos da classes com seus atributos e cria uma tabela no banco dados de acordo com esta especificação, nada mais que isto.

Ele opera em essência em modelos anêmicos. Não que não possa ter comportamentos na classe, mas eles serão ignorados quando transpõe para o banco de dados.